# When viewing a file the character 'ß' appears as ▒

Tags: utf-8

When viewing an XML File in UTF-8 which has the following character 'ß', it actually appears as '▒'. The file was created in notepad++ and all looked fine. But when viewing it in PuTTY the change appears. I have amended my PuTTY configurations as per below, but the file still contains the strange character:

- Right click Putty
- Click 'Change Settings'
- Navigate to Window > Translation
- Select 'UTF-8' from the drop down menu.
- Click 'Apply' to save the changes.

Snippet of the file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <test>Flo▒\237er Str. 53</test>
</request>
```

- All other characters appear fine e.g. 'ö', 'ü'.

Comment: Is the file properly encoded in Notepad++? Does it show "utf8" when looking in the Encoding menu?

Comment: Yes. Encoding > Encode in UTF-8

Comment: The weird thing is when I transfer it across to a unix box and view it in PuTTY, this is when the problem occurs. Even though I have changed my PuTTY configuration settings.

Comment: What program you use to view the file in the remote session over putty? (cat, vi, less, more, ..)

Comment: I use 'view'. view <filename>.... should it make a difference?

Comment: How did you copy it to your Linux box and what is the result of `locale`?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, I copied it across using FileZilla. The result of running locale is:                              LANG=en_GB.ISO8859-15
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_TIME="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.ISO8859-15"
LC_ALL=en_GB.ISO8859-15
This could be interesting, I would expect the locale to be UTF-8 for my scenario...

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, How do I change the locale?

Comment: See answer below. I hope it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your shell environment is simply set incorrectly. To temporarily set it to support UTF-8, do:

```
export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This should allow you to run `view` in the same session and the character to show correctly.

Making this change permanently depends on your Linux distribution and whether you have root access. For Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#Changing_settings_permanently

If you don't have root access you can edit `~/.bashrc` and paste the command above to the end of the file